# Trouble printing all items from a list in python

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, html-parsing

I'm trying to learn how to do web scraping, and it's not coming out in the format i would hope it would have. Here is the issue I'm running into:

```
import urllib
import re

pagelist = ["page=1","page=2","page=3","page=4","page=5","page=6","page=7","page=8","page=9","page=10"]
ziplocations = ["=30008","=30009"]

i=0
while i<len(pagelist):
    url = "http://www.boostmobile.com/stores/?" +pagelist[i]+"&zipcode=30008"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<h2 style="float:left;">(.+?)</h2>' 
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    storeName = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "Store Name=", storeName[i]
    i+=1
```

This code produces this result:
Store Name = Boost Mobile store by wireless depot
Store Name = Wal-Mart
.....
and so for 10 different stores, I'm assuming this happens because

```
while i<len(pagelist):
```

is only = to ten

so it only prints out ten of the stores instead of all stores listed on all pages.

When I change the second to last line to this

```
print storeName
```

It will print out every store name listed on each page but not in the format above  but like this:
'Boost mobile store by wireless depot', 'boost mobile store by kob wireless', 'marietta check chashing services',..... and so on for about another 120 entries. 
so how do I get it in the desired format of: "Store Name = ...." rather then: 'name','name',.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Do not parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Use a specialized tool - an `HTML Parser`.

Here's the solution using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.boostmobile.com/stores/?page={page}&zipcode={zipcode}"
num_pages = 10
zipcode = 30008

for page in xrange(1, num_pages + 1):
    url = base_url.format(page=page, zipcode=zipcode)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

    print "Page Number: %s" % page
    results = soup.find('table', class_="results")
    for h2 in results.find_all('h2'):
        print h2.text
```

It prints:

```
Page Number: 1
Boost Mobile Store by Wireless Depot
Boost Mobile Store by KOB Wireless
Marietta Check Cashing Services
...
Page Number: 2
Target
Wal-Mart
...
```

As you can see, first we find a `table` tag with `results` class - this is where the store names actually are. Then, inside the `table` we are finding all of the `h2` tags. This is more robust than relying on the `style` attribute of a tag.

---

You can also make use of [`SoupStrainer`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document). It would improve the performance since it would parse only the part of document that you specify:

```
required_part = SoupStrainer('table', class_="results")
for page in xrange(1, num_pages + 1):
    url = base_url.format(page=page, zipcode=zipcode)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), parse_only=required_part)

    print "Page Number: %s" % page
    for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
        print h2.text
```

Here we are saying: "parse only the `table` tag with the class `results`. And give us all of the `h2` tags inside it."

Also, if you want to improve performance, you can [let `BeautifulSoup` use `lxml` parser under the hood](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), "lxml", parse_only=required_part)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: that's great! Thank you, I'm still having trouble. I'm trying to make it go through several zipcodes. Is it as simple as making url = base_url.format(page=page, zipcode=(variable))

Comment: @SamK yup, and you would probably need to use nested loops. Let me know if you need help with it.

Comment: yea I must not be nesting them correctly, would you mind showing me how?

Answer (score 1):

`storeName` is an array, and you need to loop through it. Currently you are indexing into it a single time at each page, using the page number, which was probably not your intent.

Here is a correct version of your code, with the loop added.

```
import urllib
import re

pagelist = ["page=1","page=2","page=3","page=4","page=5","page=6","page=7","page=8","page=9","page=10"]
ziplocations = ["=30008","=30009"]

i=0
while i<len(pagelist):
    url = "http://www.boostmobile.com/stores/?" +pagelist[i]+"&zipcode=30008"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<h2 style="float:left;">(.+?)</h2>' 
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    storeName = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    for sn in storeName:
        print "Store Name=", sn
    i+=1
```